# Unable to indicate server_name with Apache HttpClient 5.1 and Java 11

Tags: java, ssl, java-11, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm trying to make API call to a server that uses 2-way SSL authentication. I'm using Apache HttpClient 5.1 along with Java 11. I'm loading TrustMaterial into SSL context and later creating a CloseableHttpClient to make API call, in this case a GET call. But I keep getting Connection Reset error. So, I enabled debugging on handshake `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl,handshake")`. I noticed that ClientHello was missing  **server_name** in its **extensions**. I'm thinking this might be causing the issue with connection.

Code

```
public class ClientCustomSSL {
    public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl,handshake");

        File file = new File("C:\\Mycerts.jks");
        final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(file,"passcode".toCharArray()).build();
        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(sslcontext).build();
        final HttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .build();
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
             .setConnectionManager(cm).build()) {

            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://mysite-s123/");
            final HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, clientContext)) {
                System.out.println(response.getCode() + " " + response.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }
    }
```

Error

```
javax.net.ss1|WARNING|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.291 EDT|ServerNameExtension.java: 261 | Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ss1|DEBUG|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.291 EDT|SSLExtensions.java: 260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server name
javax.net.ss1 WARNING| 01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.293 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ss1|WARNING|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.293 EDT|SignatureScheme.java: 295|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax_net.ss1|INFO|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.297 EDT|AlpnExtension.java:178|No available application protocols
javax.net.551| DEBUG (02 |main|2022-25-08 14:39:57.297 EDT|SSLExtensions. java: 260| Ignore, context unavailable extension: application layer protocol _negotiation
javax.net.ss1|DEBUG|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.297 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore,context unavailable extension: renegotiation_ info
javax.net-ss1|DEBUG|01|main|2022-07-08 14:39:57.299 EDT|ClientHello.java: 642 Produced ClientHello handshake message
"ClientHello":{
"client version":"TLSv1.2",
"random":"E1 A8 CF DD 06 87 B9 FD 6C EB FE C6 BC E3 C4 7F EE DC 22 B3 B7 AC 40 0A DO 53 7F 81 51 5D 78 D9",
"session id":"E1 A8 CF DD 06 87 B9 FD 6C EB FE C6 BC E3 C4 7F EE DC 22 B3 B7 AC 40 0A DO 78 D9", 
"cipher suites":"[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302),TLS_ECOHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(exCe2C), TLS_ECDHE_ECOSA WITH AES_128 _ GCM SHA256(exC82B), TLS_ECDHE_ECOSA_WITH_CHACHA2®_POL Y1305 _SHA256 (exCCA9)...]",
"compression methods": "00",
"extensions": [
    "status request (5)":{
    "certificate status type": ocsp
    "OCSP status request": {
        "responder id": ‹empty>
        "request extensions":{
        ‹empty>
        }
    }
},
"supported_groups (10)": {
    "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
},
"ec point formats (11)": {
    formats": [uncompressed]
},
"signature algorithms (13)": {
        "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1 sha256, ecdsa_ secp384r1_ sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_ sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa pss_ pss_sha256, dsa_sha1]
},
    "signature algorithms_cert (50)": {
        "signature schemes" : [ecdsa secp256r1 sha256, ecdsa secp384r1_ sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_ sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_ rsae_sha384, rsa pss_rsae_sha512, rsa pss_pss_sha256,dsa_sha1]
        },
        "status request_v2 (17)": {
        "cert status request":{
        "certificate status type": ocsp multi
}
]
}
javax.net.ss1|WARNING|01|main|2022-07-07 09:26:16.233 EDT| SSLSocketImp1.java: 1648| handling exception ("throwable" : {
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputstream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputstream.read (SocketInputstream.java: 140)
        at java.base/sun.security.ss1.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1501)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImp1.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1411)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImp1.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ss1.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpclientConnectionoperator.connect(DefaultHttpclientconnectionoperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpclientconnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainclientExec.establishRoute(MainclientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainclientExec.execute(MainclientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.imp1.execchain.RetryExec-execute(RetryExec-java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.imp1.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpclient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.closeableHttpclient.execute(CloseableHttpclient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl. client.closeableHttpclient. execute(closeableHttpclient. java:108)
        at ClientCustomSSL.main(ClientCustomSSL.java:62)}
```

Based on some of the StackOverflow answers, SNI extension does not require any custom configuration and should work transparently. But I don't understand why this is not working though. Can anyone please let know if I'm missing something here and point me in the right direction.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Are you really using `mysite-123` or is that a redaction? Assuming the middleware passes the name, which hc 4.5.4 mostly does though I haven't looked at 5.anything, JSSE interprets strictly the requirement for SNI to be a 'DNS name' and if the hostname it is told to connect to is **only one 'label'** (no period) or is all-numeric (like an IPaddress) it **is not used** for SNI (even though actual DNS typically can resolve a single-label name using search context).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, ```mysite-s123``` is a redaction, but my actual target site follows the same pattern